# Принцип обновления кэша на клиенте в nginx

Tags: nginx, кэширование

Вопрос касательно обновления кэшированных файлов. Все файлы стилей у меня на сервере закэшированы на 7 дней(согласно рекомендаций Google Page Insight) по правилам nginx(Expires), а в мета-теге `Cache-Control` указаны правила `no-store, must-revalidate`. Но при этом, когда я вношу правки в какой-то .css файл, то эти правки не отображаются. По идее, правило `must-revalidate` должно проверять дату изменения документа и в случае изменения выдавать пользователю обновлённый, а не кэшированный файл. Или моё представление ошибочно?

Comment: Подозреваю, ошибочно, потому что иначе кэширование вообще не имеет смысла. (Правда, как не ошибочно, я сам плохо знаю)

Comment: @andreymal ну а как тогда правки вносить? Отредактировать блок, который у всех пользователей в итоге сломается. И что? Писать им "ой, простите, подождите недельку, пока кэш очистится"?

Comment: Обычно ссылку на файл меняют каким-нибудь образом

Comment: Кешированием вообще-то браузер занимается. И у него может быть своё мнение что и когда проверять. Советы гугла рассчитаны на файлы которые меняют адрес при изменениях, нужно думать своей головой, а не слепо верить дяде